# Regex Match qustion

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match this pattern: [k1,v1][k2,v2]...

k1...kn cannont be empty while v1...vn can be.

[k,v] can apear more than 1 time.

I wrote this but it ain't work: `^(?=\[).+(?<!\]),.*(?<!\[)(?<=\])$`

Comment: To be more helpful, give the reason why it should be down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  `@"^(?:\[[^,\]]+(?:,[^\]]+)?\])+$"`

Explanation:

> Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
>
> Match the regular expression below `(?:\[[^,\]]+(?:,[^\]]+)?\])+`
>
> > Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
> >
> > Match the character “[” literally `\[`
> >
> > Match any single character NOT present in the list below `[^,\]]+`
> >
> > > Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
> > >
> > > The literal character “,” `,`
> > >
> > > The literal character “]” `\]`
> >
> > Match the regular expression below `(?:,[^\]]+)?`
> >
> > > Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `?`
> > >
> > > Match the character “,” `,`
> > >
> > > Match any character that is NOT a “]” `[^\]]+`
> > >
> > > > Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `+`
> >
> > Match the character “]” literally `\]`
>
> Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) `$`

Comment: you just added some explanation for my regex. That's all. You could get the same explanation from the link on my answer. Does it worth to accept your answer rather than mine?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
@"^(?:\[[^,\]]+(?:,[^\]]+)?\])+$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zU0cX2/1)

Comment: Thanks man! That's what I want. Never thought of **Non-Capturing group `(?:)`**. Seems like **LookAround** is not enough

Comment: I Added some explanation to your answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: pls add also the regex patterns.